# Unable to download Android Studio on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to download Android Studio for Windows from the official page https://developer.android.com/studio

I use Windows 10

When I click on the Download button and accept the terms and conditions, I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE page from my browser (Chrome). I tried multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) and clearing my browser cache, restarting the laptop. I tried multiple times across several days but I always get the same result.

I also tried to install Java Development Kit upfront and I got same result as in the screenshots below.

Is there any prerequisite that I might be missing to be able to download Android Studio?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any chrome plugins/extensions that could be blocking a download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it important for you to download it from the official website?
If not, download it from here: https://android-studio.fr.uptodown.com/windows/telecharger

Comment: I managed to download it from another location but I still find it weird that I can't do it from the official website

Comment: I suggest you install IDM so you don't have any more problems. Because as soon as a link is accessible on a site, IDM captures it. I was able to download Android studio from the official website thanks to it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello nothing is needed, it is just some configurations problems
Try:

1. Resetting your network connection and DNS-Check whether it is fine.
2. Clear your browsing data and cache.
3. Download from the official Android website.

Then restart the browsers and try to download it again.